# Angular: can I trigger a pure pipe when the input object is changed? (object reference not changed but the inside of that changed)

Tags: angular, pipe

There is a pure pipe which input is an object. Inside the object there are several another reference type properties. As I know when any of the property in the object is changed it has no effect for the pipe. Am I correct?
How can I reach when any of the internal part of object is changed it triggered the pipe? It can possible in any way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not trigger pipe, you have to switch pipe to impure and implement custom checks or create new object: `this.myObject = {...this.myObject}`